# Why is Postgres query faster than Redis query?

Tags: django, postgresql, time, redis

I am learning about Redis, and how its blazing fast since its an in-memory database. In my Django application, I have a Postgres table with about 1500 rows in it. The model only has two fields 'name' and 'occurrence'. To test out how much faster it would be to query for objects out of memory, compared to from my local database, which I believe is stored on disc, I created two queries

> 1) Simple order by query using Django objects manager
>
> 2) ZRANGE command on Redis server, getting same items back from a
>   Redis sorted set.

After making both queries, I found that getting the same number of items from a Redis sorted set took 250 times longer than it took to make the Postgres Query. Why is this ?

Script

```
import json
import redis
import datetime

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from wikipedia.models import Word

redis_server = redis.Redis("localhost")

def get_word_results(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    words = Word.objects.all().order_by('-occurrence')
    after = datetime.datetime.now()

    diff = (after - now).total_seconds() * 1000
    print(diff)

    rnow = datetime.datetime.now()
    words_redis = redis_server.zrange(name='myzset', start=0, end=-1, withscores=True)
    rafter = datetime.datetime.now()

    diff2 = (rafter - rnow).total_seconds() * 1000
    print(diff2)
```

Results

```
0.199
48.048
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember, redis is not a general purpose database.  There are some queries or uses where an old-fashioned rdbms is the way to go, and some where redis outclasses the rdbms.  Redis gives you lightning-fast reads and writes to key-value stored data.  i.e., "For a given word, I want to retrieve the number of occurrences", not "I want all of the words sorted by occurrence."

So, for example:

```
def prep_redis():
    for word in Word.objects.all():
        redis_server.set(word.name, word.occurrence)

def test_lookup_postgres(name):
    # start = datetime.datetime.now()
    p = Word.objects.get(name=name)
    # end = datetime.datetime.now()
    # diff = end - start
    # print('postgres took %s ms' % (diff * 1000,))
    return p.occurrence

def test_lookup_redis(name):
    # start = datetime.datetime.now()
    value = redis_server.get(name)
    # end = datetime.datetime.now()
    # diff = end - start
    # print('redis took %s ms' % (diff * 1000,))
    return value

def main():
    from timeit import Timer
    prep_redis()
    r_timer = Timer(lambda: test_lookup_redis('sesame'))
    p_timer = Timer(lambda: test_lookup_postgres('sesame'))
    print('For 1000 runs, redis: %s' % (r_timer.timeit(number=1000),))
    print('For 1000 runs, postgres: %s' % (p_timer.timeit(number=1000),))
```

Here we will expect redis to be faster than postgres.

In contrast, redis is remarkably slow with larger data structures because the time it takes to serialize and deserialize the data overwhelms the I/O cost:

> Speed of RAM and memory bandwidth seem less critical for global performance especially for small objects. For large objects (>10 KB), it may become noticeable though. Usually, it is not really cost-effective to buy expensive fast memory modules to optimize Redis.
>   [Redis benchmarks](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks)

Comment: Thanks 2ps, this was really helpful !

Answer (score 1):

Your test is constructing the database query but is not actually executing it. Change your line to:

```
words = list(Word.objects.order_by('-occurrence'))
```

That will force evaluation of the query. (See [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) of the documentation for more details.)

Comment: Thanks Kevin ! Both of your answers were extremely helpful in me understanding the issue more. If I could mark both as the answer I would : ) .